# Yum update only if packages are older than

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade

We had several problems with new packages that had bugs after a yum update (for ex: the latest microcode https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2020:2432 for one of our production servers caused a kernel panic and it would not boot).

I wanted to know if there is a way to update only packages that are in the repository for some time, let's say: 1 month.

This way our servers don't go down if there is a bug in a very new packaged.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, there's the flip side: a week-old package is discovered to have a bug and is repaired by a recent update. Is there a Test/QA environment you can use for this purpose?

Comment: CentOS packages *are* the stable packages.  They've already gone through testing at Red Hat and are rebuilt from their sources.  There's no qualifying metadata for CentOS packages that indicates stablility, the only supported packages are the most up to date.

Comment: @JeffSchaller The thing is that we use a variety of hardware, we cannot have a QA env for each HW combination.
This question was originated because a microcode update had an issue with an specific CPU and motherboard combo and then it was fixed by another update. If we could wait 1-2 weeks before applying a new package it would be great.
If there isn't such option in Yum or another utility, maybe I can script it.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but: consider having readily-available, documented, backout steps to updates so that you're not stuck with failed boots. I don't know of a better way to guarantee a successful patch, boot, and application functionality than a Test/QA environment.

Comment: What about raising the "metadata_expire" to a week for example? that would do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had another issue, that I wanted to have production servers update the packages later than stage and dev servers.

If possible I would choose a patch management tool like [Foreman Katello](https://theforeman.org/plugins/katello/) and multiple local yum repos.

My solution is anything than pretty but does work:

```bash
repoquery -a --pkgnarrow=updates --qf="%{name}-%{epoch}:%{version}-%{release}.%{arch} %{filetime}" |
awk -v daysago=$(date --date="7 days ago" +%s) '$NF < daysago' |
cut -f1 -d" " |
xargs yum update --assumeyes
```

**Explanation:**

- `repoquery` Lists updates and adds filetime information at the end separated by a whitespace
- `awk` Filters last section for date older than seven days (change to suit your needs)
- `cut` Split by whitespace and remove the last part (actually whitespace and timestamp)
- `xargs -r yum update` Inject list into `yum update` command. Optionally you also can filter for security updates here with `--security`.